# Splitting an jsonarray based on key with lodash underscore

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, lodash, text-processing

I am trying to get the unique items in each column of a json array. I want to convert this :

> var items = [ {"name": "Type 1","id": 13}, {"name": "Type 2","id":
>   14}, {"name": "Type 3","id": 14}, {"name": "Type 3","id": 13},
>   {"name": "Type 2","id": 12}, {"name": "Type 3","id": 12} ];

into

> [{"Type 1","Type 2","Type 3"},{12,13,14}]

This is what I tried :

```
var uniq1 = _.map(_.uniqBy(items, 'id'), 'id');
var uniq2 =_.map(_.uniqBy(items, 'name'), 'name')
console.log(uniq1,uniq2)
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/yogeshwaran/5ntfzss1/

But this seems to be an inefficient solution for my use case as my real dataset is much bigger (100000 elements with 6 keys in each element). Is there a way to get all unique values for each of the keys. I do not want to iterate over the entire set each and every time. My ideal approach would be :
1. Split the array based on keys.
2. Then find the unique in the each of the split.
3. Join the results.

Thanks.

Comment: You can either use vanilla js or new js Sets(watch out for browser support) to make ir more efficient

Comment: Are you doing this in the browser for a web application or just for processing JSON data? If the latter, I recommend using `jq` for handling large JSON datasets and has a lot of nice [helper functions](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#TypesandValues).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination `_.values()` to convert the object to array, `_.zip()` to transpose the arrays, and then map them with `_.uniq()`:

```js
var items = [
  {"name": "Type 1","id": 13, "position": "manager"},
  {"name": "Type 2","id": 14, "position": "manager"},
  {"name": "Type 3","id": 14, "position": "manager"},
  {"name": "Type 3","id": 13, "position": "worker"},
  {"name": "Type 2","id": 12, "position": "worker"},
  {"name": "Type 3","id": 12, "position": "manager"}
];

var result = _.zip.apply(_, items.map(_.values)).map(_.uniq);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```